# localStorage returning Object

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

Previously any time I have used `localStorage` I have always have to use `JSON.stringify` to retrieve the code as an object.

However I have just used `localStorage` in the latest version of Chromium `Version 42.0.2308.0 canary (64-bit)` and this is what it returned:

```
localStorage
Storage {debug: "undefined", uid: "3", length: 2} 

typeof localStorage
"object"
```

When and which browsers/phones now support `localStorage` as objects?

Comment: `typeof localStorage` isn't checking the *contents* of localStorage.

Comment: what does that even mean in this context :)?

Answer (score 1):

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage:

"Storage objects are a recent addition to the standard. As such they may not be present in all browsers. You can work around this by inserting one of the following two codes at the beginning of your scripts, allowing use of localStorage object in implementations which do not natively support it."

Basically, it *should* be returning a type of Object, but some browsers are not that compatible. You can put one of the following two scripts at the beginning of your code to work around this:

```
if (!window.localStorage) {
  Object.defineProperty(window, "localStorage", new (function () {
    var aKeys = [], oStorage = {};
    Object.defineProperty(oStorage, "getItem", {
      value: function (sKey) { return sKey ? this[sKey] : null; },
      writable: false,
      configurable: false,
      enumerable: false
    });
    Object.defineProperty(oStorage, "key", {
      value: function (nKeyId) { return aKeys[nKeyId]; },
      writable: false,
      configurable: false,
      enumerable: false
    });
    Object.defineProperty(oStorage, "setItem", {
      value: function (sKey, sValue) {
        if(!sKey) { return; }
        document.cookie = escape(sKey) + "=" + escape(sValue) + "; expires=Tue, 19 Jan 2038 03:14:07 GMT; path=/";
      },
      writable: false,
      configurable: false,
      enumerable: false
    });
    Object.defineProperty(oStorage, "length", {
      get: function () { return aKeys.length; },
      configurable: false,
      enumerable: false
    });
    Object.defineProperty(oStorage, "removeItem", {
      value: function (sKey) {
        if(!sKey) { return; }
        document.cookie = escape(sKey) + "=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT; path=/";
      },
      writable: false,
      configurable: false,
      enumerable: false
    });
    this.get = function () {
      var iThisIndx;
      for (var sKey in oStorage) {
        iThisIndx = aKeys.indexOf(sKey);
        if (iThisIndx === -1) { oStorage.setItem(sKey, oStorage[sKey]); }
        else { aKeys.splice(iThisIndx, 1); }
        delete oStorage[sKey];
      }
      for (aKeys; aKeys.length > 0; aKeys.splice(0, 1)) { oStorage.removeItem(aKeys[0]); }
      for (var aCouple, iKey, nIdx = 0, aCouples = document.cookie.split(/\s*;\s*/); nIdx < aCouples.length; nIdx++) {
        aCouple = aCouples[nIdx].split(/\s*=\s*/);
        if (aCouple.length > 1) {
          oStorage[iKey = unescape(aCouple[0])] = unescape(aCouple[1]);
          aKeys.push(iKey);
        }
      }
      return oStorage;
    };
    this.configurable = false;
    this.enumerable = true;
  })());
}
```

"Here is another, less exact, imitation of the localStorage object. It is simpler than the previous one, but it is compatible with old browsers, like Internet Explorer < 8 (tested and working even in Internet Explorer 6). It also makes use of cookies."

```
if (!window.localStorage) {
  window.localStorage = {
    getItem: function (sKey) {
      if (!sKey || !this.hasOwnProperty(sKey)) { return null; }
      return unescape(document.cookie.replace(new RegExp("(?:^|.*;\\s*)" + escape(sKey).replace(/[\-\.\+\*]/g, "\\$&") + "\\s*\\=\\s*((?:[^;](?!;))*[^;]?).*"), "$1"));
    },
    key: function (nKeyId) {
      return unescape(document.cookie.replace(/\s*\=(?:.(?!;))*$/, "").split(/\s*\=(?:[^;](?!;))*[^;]?;\s*/)[nKeyId]);
    },
    setItem: function (sKey, sValue) {
      if(!sKey) { return; }
      document.cookie = escape(sKey) + "=" + escape(sValue) + "; expires=Tue, 19 Jan 2038 03:14:07 GMT; path=/";
      this.length = document.cookie.match(/\=/g).length;
    },
    length: 0,
    removeItem: function (sKey) {
      if (!sKey || !this.hasOwnProperty(sKey)) { return; }
      document.cookie = escape(sKey) + "=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT; path=/";
      this.length--;
    },
    hasOwnProperty: function (sKey) {
      return (new RegExp("(?:^|;\\s*)" + escape(sKey).replace(/[\-\.\+\*]/g, "\\$&") + "\\s*\\=")).test(document.cookie);
    }
  };
  window.localStorage.length = (document.cookie.match(/\=/g) || window.localStorage).length;
}
```

**EDIT**

The part of this answer that I didn't put in quotes is *nearly* word-by-word on that webpage, except I put an explanation.

Comment: Umm I wasn't asking if localStorage is a new thing :D Sorry if I wasn't clear, I was more pointing out that it seems in modern browsers they will automatically return an `object` rather than just strings if what you stored in the storage was an `object` already

Comment: @JamieHutber Yes, and that's exactly it. The fact that you have to JSON stringify means that the browser doesn't support Storage objects (at least that's what I'm thinking)

Answer (score 0):

The `localStorage` (object) was always an object-like construct. That means, we were always be able to access data in a way like

```
localStorage.foo = 42;
```

to retrieve that data, we could call `localStorage.foo` or use the offered helper functions like

```
localStorage.getItem('foo');
```

But that the `localStorage` in fact is not an Object, you can easily call

```
Object.prototype.toString.call(localStorage); // === [object Storage]
```

Comment: Umm interesting point you raise.... I do believe you're right, previously I had to use JSON.parse on an object stored inside of a property of localStorage